# Selenium element not selectable for a kendo ui element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, c#

I am having an issue with an element which works with a mouse click and there are some items from which one has to be selected but its unselectable is set to on.

Whenever I try to select the elements I get back an error the element is not visible so may not be interacted with, but the element is visible.

We are using a Kendo UI in there.

The Html code:

```
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox">
<li class="k-button" unselectable="on">
<span unselectable="on">Sector 1</span>
<span class="k-icon k-delete" unselectable="on">delete</span>
</li>
</ul>
<input class="k-input" style="width: 25px;" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds" class="bigselect" name="ProfileEditSharedModel.SelectedIndustrySectorIds" multiple="multiple" data-val-required="*" data-val="true" data-placeholder="Select Sectors..." data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="1">Sector 1</option>
<option value="2">Sector 2</option>
<option value="3">Sector 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using **JavascriptExecutor**

I can either use this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#{0}')
.data('kendoMultiSelect')
.value({1});", "ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds", 3,));
```

or

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds')
.data('kendoMultiSelect')
.value([values]);", "ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds", 3,));
```

I was using a kendoMultiSelect there

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    public void ResetKendoDropdown(string identifier, string defaultText)
    {
        var kendoElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Id(identifier));

        kendoElement.Click();

        while (kendoElement.FindElement(By.ClassName("k-dropdown-wrap")).Text != defaultText)
        {
            kendoElement.FindElement(By.ClassName("k-dropdown-wrap")).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowUp);
        }

        kendoElement.Click();
    }
```